# How can I convert html to draftjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have tried basic packages but I don't seem to get whats going on,

Here is something that I tried;

```
const {
  convertFromHTML,
  ContentState
} = require('draft-js');
const htmlToDraft = require('html-to-draftjs');

const converter = () => {
    const sampleMarkup =
      '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ><br />' +
      '<a href="http://www.google.com">Example link</a>';

    const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
    const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocksFromHTML);

    console.log('state: ', state);
}

converter();
```

It was really clear on which library to use.
I am getting weird looking outputs, what I expect looks something like this;

```
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "depth": 0,
      "inlineStyleRanges": [
        {
          "length": 9,
          "style": "BOLD",
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "length": 12,
          "style": "ITALIC",
          "offset": 11
        }
      ],
      "entityRanges": [
        {
          "length": 12,
          "key": 0,
          "offset": 25
        }
      ],
      "data": {},
      "text": "Bold text, Italics text\n\nexample link ",
      "key": "9jc4q",
      "type": "unstyled"
    }
  ],
  "entityMap": {
    "0": {
      "type": "LINK",
      "mutability": "MUTABLE",
      "data": {
        "url": "http://www.google.com",
        "targetOption": "_blank"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any insights ? (code in server side )

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-draftjs

Comment: @MakwanaPrahlad Tried that, it giving me this output...      EditorState {
  _immutable:
   Record { "allowUndo": true, "currentContent": ContentState { "entityMap": [object Object], "blockMap": OrderedMap { someObjects here } }

Comment: @MakwanaPrahlad html-to-draftjs  is giving me -> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Plz not use version 1.2.0 it has build issues.

Comment: @MakwanaPrahlad I'm using 1.5.0

Answer (score 3):

```
const sampleMarkup =
  '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ><br />' +
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>';

const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
);

this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
};
```

Comment: I'm getting: `Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'IConvertFromHTMLConfig'` for `convertFromHTML` function

Answer (score 2):

I am following the code and my code is running fine.  I don't have any problem, you can check by copying my code.

```
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
import { ContentState, EditorState } from 'draft-js';


const htmlToDraftBlocks = (html) => {
 const blocksFromHtml = htmlToDraft(html);
 const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocksFromHtml;
 const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks, entityMap);
 const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
 return editorState;
}


useEffect(()=>{
setEditorState(htmlToDraftBlocks("<p>Hello</p>"));
},[])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Saying please use the function and saying it's 100% working is super sketch mate. Instead you should give a short description of what the code does

Comment: Really It's working 110% 